# How to setup Jenkins host to kick a job on the vmware ubuntu mounted on a windows machine?

Tags: jenkins

I have a vmware ubuntu mounted on a windows machine. Is it possible for Jenkins host (linux box) to kick a job on the vmware ubuntu? If so, how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the HTTP request to trigger the job. You should include Authentication token both in the job and in the HTTP request.

First, enable the job trigger. You need to configure the job, under Build Triggers, check the box next to "Trigger Builds Remotely". You should provide an authentication token for validation. 
Then trigger it with http://yourjenkinsserver.com/job/JobName/build?token=yourtokentext.

More info [here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/). If you need to specify job parameters, check [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).